# Query performance counters from powershell

Tags: powershell, windows, performance-counters

I am trying this script to query performance counters in different localized windows server versions. 
http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/07/19/querying-performance-counters-from-powershell/

Everything works as in the article, well partially :-)

I am trying to access a counter ID 3906 Terminal Services Session and works well for English windows. However for example in French and German that counter doesn't exist under that ID.

I think I figured to find the exact counter under ID 1548 in french and German, but that ID in English is something completely different. Anybody seen this behavior on the performance counters?